# How to manipulate array in emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I am currently creating a simple game program in emu8086. Using arrow keys I am able to print asterisk in every direction I want. The problem is there is a requirement that if I already printed 5 asterisk the tail of the asterisk should be remove so that the body of my asterisk will remain 5 every print.

from my research, mostly used array but I have no idea yet how to manipulate this in array, since I don't know how to track the array's tail and position for me to be able to print space to delete the tail.

like:

```
1. *
2. *
3. *
4. *
5. *
```

after clicking a direction it should look like..
in this case it's just for the down direction.. how about combination of other directions?

```
1. 
2.*
3.*
4.*
5.*
6.*
```

here's my printing code

```
continue:

mov ah, 2   ;print asterisk
mov dl, "*"
int 21h 

continue2:
mov ch, 32  ;hide blinking cursor
mov ah, 1
int 10h 

mov ah, 00h ;input direction
int 16h  

cmp ah, up
je  up        
cmp ah, left
je  left
cmp ah, down
je  down 
cmp ah, right
je  right
```

Comment: How do you set position of next asterisk? The [`int 21h,2`](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-2.html) does print it at default next position (to STDOUT), not up/down/right/left by some key input. Also as this is DOS, why don't you write directly to VRAM, as you are working on "game", in the age of 8086 PC XT if you wanted to write a game, you had to cut out every middle-man, including very slow BIOS/DOS calls. BTW, do you understand C/C++ well, so I can use C examples in answer?

Comment: I was thinking about answering this, but I tried actually to use `emu8086` and it silently compiles `mov [di+bx*2],ax` as `mov [di+bx],ax` without any warning or error. I'm not willing to support such inferior tool (it's not the first time I'm hitting some weird problem with emu8086).

Comment: we are actually required to use the emu8086. it's like a snake game but it prints the body (asterisks) one by one by the user

Comment: they gave us a clue that we can use arrays but I'm having a hard time to understand how it will work.

Comment: Also while I was checking emu8086, I found out the very first "Hello world" example is working by writing the data directly into video ram, skipping the slow BIOS/DOS `int 10h`/`int 21h` services. Maybe you should read about the VGA text mode video memory organization under DOS, and check that example, to see how it works. Although to read keyboard state the BIOS `int 16h` is OK for simple snake game (I just hope I remember those interrupts correctly), reading the keyboard directly from port 60h (or 61h?) will clash with BIOS handler, and you shouldn't need that for snake game.

Answer (score 1):

You can use so called ["ring buffer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), if you know the maximum length of snake.

The "arrays" in assembly is just continuous area of memory, with the structure defined by your code.

Let's say you will have snake 5 asterisks long at most, then I would use buffer of 6 [x, y] positions to define that, 5 positions are asterisks from head to tail, 6th position is the previous tail position, i.e. where the space is printed to "erase" tail.

I would actually re-arrange that in the code a bit, having such buffer with positions long some power of two (next power of two after 6 is 8, if your snake will grow, to fill screen, then you need 80*25=2000 positions at most, and next power of two is 2048). And I would keep around index to the head element (then just pick direction toward next body parts as you wish, I would probably put head last during init, so buffer[0] would contain the "space" tail, buffer[1] last asterisk "tail", ... buffer[5] would be "head" asterisk, and I would keep around that headIndex=5 (or rather directly memory offset as `headOffset = 10`, as each element would be 2 bytes (`[x,y]`) and 5*2 = 10).

So you have some "ring buffer" for body parts positions in data section:

```
BUFFER_SIZE  EQU  2*8  ; or 2*2048 for growing snake
    ; everything will be "2*", because each position is 2 bytes big

snakeLength:
    dw      ?
headOffset:
    dw      ?
positions:
    db      BUFFER_SIZE DUP (?)
```

And some code, which will initialize snake length to 5, then first 6 pairs of bytes in `positions` as where the snake starts (including the "space" tail at first position!), and the head offset to `10` (5th position byte-pair in buffer).

Now to print snake, you will load the `headOffset` and `snakeLength`, and do "snakeLength" many times:

- fetch two bytes from `positions + offset`, as [x,y]
- print asterisk there
- decrement offset by two
- `and <register with offset>,(BUFFER_SIZE-2)`, which will make it to point to the last element of memory in case offset was 0 already (that's the reason, why power of two, to allow me to wrap around the "ring buffer" by single `and` instruction and bit masking operation).

And finally one more iteration, but this time printing space, not asterisk (for the final element).

That's about how to draw the snake defined in such array.

How to "move" it in some direction, let's say (-1, 0) (to the left):

- read `headOffset` value
- read current position of head from `[positions + headOffset]`
- increment offset by 2
- `and <register with offset>,(BUFFER_SIZE-2)` makes it point to next element in buffer
- add (-1, 0) to current head position
- store that updated position to `[positions + offset]`
- store offset as new `headOffset` (which will make the last tail asterisk position now the new "space" tail, and the previous "space" tail is out of reach with the same snakeLength).

After you will draw this new state of data, the snake will "move" to the left by one step.

How to grow snake: same as move, but you also update `snakeLength` by +1, so the last two elements of buffer are still used as previous asterisk+space tail, keeping the tail at the same position, while head moved ahead. (you can grow the snake only by +1 in each step with this method, as you don't add new body parts to the tail ... but that's exactly how old snake games work, when you eat some bigger food which makes your snake grow by N parts, it is done over N next steps, not instantly).

So you have array of 8 positions, from which only 6 are used. Which 6 are used is defined by `headOffset`, which goes around and wraps around (from offset 0 going "down" is back to offset 14 (8*2-2), and from offset 14 going up means landing at offset 0, so the "ring buffer" is warping around, as "ring", without any beginning or end).

---

Alternative is to have array of 6 positions, and when you move the snake, you literally move data in the array from position *i* to position *i-1*, and then writing the new head position to the last array element. This probably simpler to understand at first try, but the "ring buffer" solution is superior because you don't have to move block of memory every time the snake moves, you just add new head and adjust offset/length data, instead of moving positions in memory, you move the offset by which you access the data. (with 1500 parts long snake that means saving almost 3000 bytes `memmove` just by setting up one new element and updating offset). The price for this is introduction of the offset warping logic (to go from offset 14 to 0 and from 0 to 14) every time you move from one element to next, but that is done by single `and` instruction, so it will be still much faster than copying memory of buffer.

---

emu8086 is inferior, and your lector should update the tools and course (how about NASM + dosbox + some neat debugger, most of universities have very likely still some turbo debugger student-licenses around from 199x era).

Comment: BTW, this way you will get blinking body part, when you go through the position where the last space is drawn (especially if the snake is growing, so several parts of snake are going through). To avoid that, you should draw from the end toward head instead, drawing the space first, then the body. Actually if you know the screen content is intact, you may draw just the space to erase last body part, when snake moves (not-grows), and draw only head. Rest of body are asterisks, so re-using what is already on screen is OK, without redrawing them again every time. But that's about draw-logic tricks

Comment: thank you for your effort Sir. I will try and understand your method.